# WordPress sub sub menu list

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a multi level menu in WordPress like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum 1.1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum 1.2</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum 2.1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum 3.1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum 3.2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum 2.2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum 1.3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When I am in page "Lorem Ipsum 3.1", I want to show all menu items in list from "Lorem Ipsum 1.2" like this:

```
Lorem Ipsum 2.1
    Lorem Ipsum 3.1
    Lorem Ipsum 3.2
Lorem Ipsum 2.2
```

Using this code:

```
<?php
    if($post->post_parent)
        $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
    else
        $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
    if ($children) { ?>
        <ul>
            <?php echo $children; ?>
        </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

It only shows the menu list:

- Lorem Ipsum 3.1
- Lorem Ipsum 3.2

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`wp_list_pages`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) does what the name implies - lists Pages. Your Menu structure isn't looked at, so how you have your menu set up isn't particularly relevant, what matters is the Page hierarchy. Does your page hierarchy match the Menu's?

If you have a Menu set up, it may be easier to use the normal [`wp_nav_menu`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) and then use CSS to hide/show sub menus as needed. The CSS will go something like this:

```
/* Hide sub menus by default */
nav li ul{
    display: none;
}
/* Always show the current menu item's children */
nav .current-menu-parent ul{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: You're right @DACrosby using wp_list_pages to get all the menu item lists and to style list with ".current_page_ancestor" is a solution. Thnx